# How to filter a table by a relation to another table in MYSQL, with a concatenate column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using MYSQL, I have 2 table : Contacts and Categories

```
+------+---------+
| id   | title   |
+------+---------+
|   10 | Cat     |
|   11 | John    |
|   12 | Sam     |
+------+---------+
```

and the categories

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | id_contact | category |
+------+------------+----------+
|    1 |         10 | C#       |
|    2 |         10 | WPF      |
|    3 |         11 | PHP      |
|    4 |         11 | JQuery   |
|    5 |         12 | MySQL    |
|    6 |         12 | MSSQL    |
|    7 |         12 | PHP      |
+------+------------+----------+
```

I want to select for all the contacts that have a category of PHP in this case the selection result would be :

```
+------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | title   | categories          |
+------+---------+---------------------+    
|   11 | John    | PHP , JQuery        |   
|   12 | Sam     | MySQL , MSSQL , PHP |
+------+---------+---------------------+
```

with a column that contains all the categories concatenated and separated by "," .
please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both tables first the use MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate the rows.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.category) categories
FROM    Contacts a
        INNER JOIN categories b
            ON a.ID = b.id_contact
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Title
HAVING  SUM(b.category = 'php') > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63c7a/2)

This condition `HAVING  SUM(b.category = 'php') > 0` filters only records where there is atleast 1 record of `php` in the category.

Comment: Oh WOW, THANKS, you saved me a lot. i wish i could vote you 1000 times